# Как выдрессировать самца кота?

Tags: java, servlet

у меня стоит Apache Tomcat 8. Я запускаю самый простой сервлет , все норме грузится. Но проблема  в том, что внося изменения в код классов приходится перезагружать кота. Отсюда можно сделать выводы, что кот куда-то к себе периодически копирует классы сервлета? Как сделать, что бы он последнюю версию сервлета обрабатывал?

сам проект небольшой, вот он на гитхабе : [нажми на меня](https://github.com/voipp/test-servlet/tree/master/jss/src/jss)

что бы не создавать новую тему. Скажите, зачем прога просит кидать классы(одна из возможностей работы сервлета) . Ведь она позже их дизассемблирует и добавит свой код. Проще кидать ей исходники

Comment: кошки плохо поддаются дрессировке. а как вы деплоите приложение ? у него есть админка, по правилам надо или через нее (war файлами) или через командную строку.

Comment: я просто копирую.Все теперь понял

Comment: не забывайте оставлять war файлы заказчикам, мы вам будем очень благодарны, когда придется деплоить.

Comment: > приходится перезагружать кота

Можно через админку перезапускать приложение.

*`<offtop>Если что, "Tomcat" это не "кот Том", а самец кота, "кошак"<offtop/>`*

Comment: вы не указали самое главное какой IDE пользуетесь, потому что большинство из них имееют встроеные средства для того чтоб автоматизировать работу с application server's

Comment: была такая проблема, в `Intellije Idea` она решилась очень просто - каждый раз отправлял проект на полный ребилд перед деплоем

Comment: я работаю в eclipse se edition. ee edition устанавливать не хотелось бы

Comment: установил intelliJIdea ultimate

Comment: Если ничего не настраивали, томкат по умолчанию перезапускает ваше приложение при обновлении файлов. Копируйте .war-файл в webapps, этого должно хватить. Если деплоите не руками, а через IDE, возможно это глюк IDE. Eclipse этим особенно известен. Помогают многочисленные Clean-ы, Restart-ы и переход на Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна возможность быстро перезапустить приложение, состоит в том, чтобы отправить соответствующий запрос менеджеру Кота, с указанием приложения. [Tomcat Manager App HOW-TO (Reload An Existing Application)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application)

Например, что-то вроде этого:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/reload?path=/examples
```

Answer (score 1):

Код компилируется в .war или .jar(как правило)-файл. Который собственно и деплоит томкат. А после компиляц3ии твой код становится статичным, поэтому при любых изменениях в коде код перекомпилируется и как следствие заново деплоится. Можно использовать языки сценариев, но про это я не расскажу.